# CiviMail - copied mailings incorrectly "remember" recipients

Tags: civimail, smartgroups

We have a smart group we want to send a mailing to. The mailing (on the first tab) indicates "~458 recipients". But the smart group itself says it currently has 244 contacts.

The smart group is the only choice selected in the recipients for this mailing.

Is this a bug?  Or are we missing something?

**EDIT**

This looks like a deeper and more serious problem. It looks like maybe copied mailings are "remembering" the groups that were selected as recipients, even if you edit the recipients in the UI to include only one group.

Or "remembering" some of the recipients, anyway.  In one test, I copied a previous mailing that had many groups as recipients. I deleted *all* of the groups from the recipients, leaving a blank recipients field, and it still estimates ~390 recipients. Which is much less than the number estimated when it had all the groups, but obviously not *zero*, as it should be.

Comment: What version of Civi and CMS are you using?

Comment: CiviCRM 4.7.1 and Drupal 7.4.1